# Issue while deploying the Orbeon Form builder portlet

Tags: ant, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, orbeon

I want to deploy the Form Runner separately, For the same reason I tried to create the proxy-portlet with reference to the following link, https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Portal-~-Liferay-Proxy-Portlet-Guide.

I tried the following command to generate the Proxy-Portlet, `ant proxy-portlet-war`

The build gets success and generated the war file (`orbeon-4.7.0.pre.20150129-proxy-portlet.war`) then I renamed the war file to `proxy-portlet.war`

Then I tried to deploy the `proxy-portlet.war` file on Liferay by copying the war file in deploy folder and started the server. While deploying the war file, I am getting the following error.

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\OpenXava\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapp
s\proxy-portlet
14:48:33,265 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][HotDeployEvent:130] Plugin proxy-portlet requires marketp
lace-portlet
14:48:33,266 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][HotDeployImpl:198] Deploying proxy-portlet from queue
14:48:33,267 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][PluginPackageUtil:1016] Reading plugin package for proxy-
portlet
14:48:33,275 ERROR [localhost-startStop-2][HotDeployImpl:211] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.H
otDeployException: Error registering plugins for proxy-portletproxy-portlet
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering plugins for proxy-portlet
proxy-portlet
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHo
tDeployListener.java:46)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PluginPackageHo
tDeployListener.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:208)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)

        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextList
ener.java:164)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListene
r.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44
)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLife
cycle.java:54)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextL
istener.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The moduleId /proxy-portlet/6.2.1/war is not correct
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.ModuleId.<init>(ModuleId.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.ModuleId.getInstance(ModuleId.java:35)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageImpl.<init>(PluginPackageImpl.java:63)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil._readPluginPackageProperties(PluginPackageUti
l.java:978)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil._readPluginPackageServletContext(PluginPackag
eUtil.java:1048)
        at com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil.readPluginPackageServletContext(PluginPackage
Util.java:201)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PluginPackage
HotDeployListener.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PluginPackageHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PluginPackageHo
tDeployListener.java:61)
        ... 24 more
29 Jan, 2015 2:48:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:48:33,307 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][PortletHotDeployListener:343] Registering portlets for pr
oxy-portlet
 INFO [org.orbeon.private.orbeon.embedding] initializing Form Runner proxy portlet
14:48:33,718 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][PortletHotDeployListener:490] 1 portlet for proxy-portlet
 is available for use
```

What is the issue? Did I miss some configuration? How do I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the error appears but the portlet deploys anyway, at least that's what I have observed. If it doesn't, try restarting Liferay.